# Modifying a verb, clause, and sentence

Tags: heading

Heads of a clause and a sentence are verbs. Doesn’t it mean modifying a verb and modifying a clause and sentence are the same?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your question is more than confusing and has little truth in it. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to understand how to ask a proper question.

Comment: In certain theories, heads of a clause and a sentence are verbs. In other theories, that's not the case. Are you asking whether "clause" and "sentence" mean the same thing? In some theories, they might, though I don't know of any.

Comment: @John Lawler prescriptively right?

Comment: @user2039 That question no verb.

Comment: Well, the head of a clause is a verb, as is the head of a VP. Coordination constructions are different, though.

Comment: @BillJ I thought the head of a clause was a predicate?

Comment: The head of a clause is a verb phrase, and the head of a VP is a verb, so it's best to refer to the verb as the head word of the clause.

Comment: Call it the _ultimate_ head, if you like.